# Multiple VLC icons in Lubuntu 18.04 System Tray

Tags: 18.04, lubuntu, vlc, lts

I run VLC 3.0.8. Vetinari on Lubuntu 18.04 LTS.

As soon as I open VLC, five VLC icons appear on System Tray.

[image]

I have tried several times a suggested solution

VLC/Tools/Preferences/Interface/"Allow only one instance" with and without 
combining it with the "Enqueue with..." option next to it, but to no avail.

The VLC player works with no problems so it is just a question of being distracted/annoyed by these icons.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: does it still happen when you use the terminal to open VLC? i.e. does it happen no matter how you open it or might it be something to do with one particular launcher or file

Comment: I've just opened the VLC via terminal. The same happens. I get the following message in the terminal:

VLC media player 3.0.8 Vetinari (revision 3.0.8-0-gf350b6b5a7)
[000056002ce1b570] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.

(vlc:27223): dbind-WARNING **: 20:27:24.860: Error retrieving accessibility bus address: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.a11y.Bus was not provided by any .service files
[000056002ceabe00] main playlist: playlist is empty
QObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread